# Typescript error got undefined with useState hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

Im new to graphql so I decided to follow this [guide](https://medium.com/make-it-heady/part-2-building-full-stack-web-app-with-postgraphile-and-react-client-side-1c5085c5a182).

However I got an error when querying (step 7) :

```
Argument of type '({ __typename?: "User"; } & Pick<User, "email" | "id" | "name" | "createdAt">)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(prevState: undefined) => undefined'.
  Type '({ __typename?: "User"; } & Pick<User, "email" | "id" | "name" | "createdAt">)[]' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: undefined): undefined'.  TS2345

    37 |       if (data && data.allUsers) {
    38 |         if (data && data.allUsers && data.allUsers.nodes) {
  > 39 |           setUsers(data.allUsers.nodes);
       |                    ^
    40 |         }
    41 |       }
    42 |     }
```

Here is the component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useGetUsers } from '../utils/services'
import { User } from '../generated/graphql'

const Users: React.FC = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState()
    const { data, error, loading } = useGetUsers()
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (data) {
            if (data && data.allUsers && data.allUsers.nodes) {
                setUsers(data.allUsers.nodes)
            }
        }
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        if (loading) {
            console.log(loading)
        }
    }, [data, error, loading])

    return (
        <>
            <h2>Hello users,</h2>
            {users &&
                users.length > 0 &&
                users.map((user: User, index: number) => (
                    <p key={`user_${index}`}>
                        {user.name}{' '}
                    </p>
                ))}
        </>
    )
}

export default Users
```

However it works when I use

```js
data.allUsers.nodes
```

Like this :

```js
{data && data.allUsers ? (
        data.allUsers.nodes &&
        data.allUsers.nodes.length > 0 &&
        data.allUsers.nodes.map((user: User, index: number) => (
          <p key={`user_${index}`}>{user.name}</p>
        ))
      ) : (
        <React.Fragment />
      )}
```

And of course I've removed `setUsers` in the `useEffect()` hooks.

I notice that I had to set strict to false in my `.tsconfig.json` file.

I would like to know why I m not able to use the setUsers hooks? Why I got that error and how to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: no need to duplicate data in local state ... just use `const users = loading ? [] : data.allUsers.nodes;` or `const users = data ? [] : data.allUsers.nodes;`before return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState()
```

should be:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
```

Comment: an empty array is inferred to be `never[]` if no type is specified.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `useState` without setting an initial value, typescript doesn't know what value that state is expected to be.  You need to declare it explicitly by setting the generic.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>();
```

Now typescript knows that our state can only be an array of `User` objects or `undefined`.

If we want to exclude the possibility of `undefined`, we can initialize it with an empty array `[]`.  We still need to provide the generic to specify what type of elements are in the array.  But now `users` is always an array of zero or more `User` objects.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);
```

So of your runtime checks become unnecessary when we have proper typings.   With the `useState` line above, your `return` becomes:

```
return (
    <>
        <h2>Hello users,</h2>
        {users.map((user, index) => (
            <p key={`user_${index}`}>
                {user.name}{' '}
            </p>
        ))}
    </>
)
```

It's ok to `map` on empty array, so we don't need to check anything.  We also don't need to declare the types for `user` and `index` because they are already known based on the type of the `users` array.